# Могу ли я выбрать anchor.left или anchor.right в зависимости от значения bool переменной в QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qml

Доброго времени суток!

У меня имеется модель списка сообщений в диалоге между двумя людьми. Для каждого сообщения имеется bool переменная, которая хранит true если сообщение отправлено мной, и false, если сообщение пришло мне.

На данный момент вот так выглядит описание делегата:

```
delegate:  Rectangle {
                width: msg_text.width
                height: msg_text.height
                color: "#000000"
                opacity: 0.2
                Text {
                    id: msg_text
                    color: "#000000"
                    text: model.message
                }
            }
```

Я хотел бы сделать, чтобы мои сообщения отображались справа, то есть для них должен быть `anchor.right: parent.right`, а для сообщений другого пользователя `anchor.left: parent.left`. Могу ли я вставить в описание делегата JavaScript код, который будет прикреплять сообщение к левой или правой границе, в зависимости от переменной bool?

В моем представлении это выглядит вот так, но QML ругается на неожиданную лексему if:

```
delegate:  Rectangle {
                if (model.fromClient) {
                    anchors.right = parent.right
                }
                else anchors.left = parent.left
           }
```

Отходя от моей конкретной задачи, вопрос можно сформулировать так: можно ли с помощью ветвления задавать свойства объектам в QML?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос в документации Qt для Anchors.

С моей проблемой помогло справиться значение `undefined`, которое удаляет свойство. В итоге код теперь выглядит вот так:

```
delegate:  Rectangle {
                id: message_rect

                anchors.left: model.fromClient ? undefined : parent.left
                anchors.right: model.fromClient ? parent.right : undefined

               ...
```